# Passing named arguments through magrittr

Tags: r, piping, magrittr

I am trying to implement magrittr's piping syntax and getting stuck very early. I have read everything I can find on it online but I just don't see how to pass named arguments though the `%>%` function.

I would like:

```
Nsamp+2 %>% seq(0, 1, length.out = .)
```

To do the same as:

```
seq(0,1,length.out=Nsamp+2)
```

Comment: Try `(Nsamp + 2) %>% seq(0, 1, length.out = . )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Victorp pointed out

```
Nsamp <- 3
(Nsamp + 2) %>% seq(0, 1, length.out = . )
# [1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00
```

should work just fine.